# Page not found | Can't serve media files with Django

Tags: python, django

That's the bit of code that causes the problem:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="{{ movie_path }}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**The error message:**

```
Using the URLconf defined in fergana_api.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
api/schema/ [name='api-schema']
api/docs/ [name='api-docs']
api/
[name='all-runs']
tests/<slug:test_session_id> [name='single-run']
tests/<slug:test_session_id>/<slug:test_name> [name='single-test']
^files/(?P<path>.*)$
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, vol/web/media/36/movies/movie.mt4, didn’t match any of these.
```

I'm trying to serve a mp4 file from a volume that's outside the project. I thought I could render the page by providing the absolute path to the file, since it's how I'd do it if I tried to open that page as an html file in browser.

But this just doesn't seem to work out though I see that **'The current path'** looks exactly as it should look.

Not sure it's required in this case, but it's my **urls.py** for the app

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.AllRunsView.as_view(), name='all-runs'),
    path('tests/<slug:test_session_id>', views.SingleRunView.as_view(), name='single-run'),
    path('tests/<slug:test_session_id>/<slug:test_name>', views.SingleTestView.as_view(), name='single-test'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class SingleTestView(View):
    def get(self, request, test_session_id, test_name):
        run = Runner.objects.get(id=test_session_id)

        movies_dir_path = to_file(run.artifacts_dir_path, 'movies')
        movie_path = to_file(movies_dir_path, test_name.replace('-', '_') + '.mp4')

        context = {
            'movie_path': movie_path
        }

        return render(request, "presenter/single_test.html", context)
```

**settings.py**

```
# under what url to serve static files in prod
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/files/'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static_files'

# location of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static'
]
```

**Absolute path to movies dir:**
/vol/web/media/36/movies/movie.mt4

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide an url  not a path as src:

```
<source src="{{ movie_path }}" ....
```

movie_path needs to be something like

```
files/36/movies/movie.mp4
```

because you set MEDIA_URL='files' which you can find in the error message as

```
^files/(?P<path>.*)$
```

Comment: but how do I exactly make the url pick up the files?

Comment: see this example for urlpattern in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development